# Concatenate configuration with groovy

Tags: gradle, groovy

In my `.build.gradle`, I have defined a specific configuration :

```
project.ext.envConfigFiles = [
  aaaDebug: ".env.aaa",
  aaaRelease: ".env.aaa",
  bbbDebug: ".env.bbb",
  bbbRelease: ".env.bbb"
]
```

This configuration is taken from the [react-native-config](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config) documentation and works very well (build **OK**).

But I'd like a dynamic configuration, from a table. For example :

```
def variants = [
  'aaa',
  'bbb',
  ...
]

def variantsConfig = []
variantsJson.each { name ->
    variantsConfig.push("${name}Debug: .env.${name}")        
    variantsConfig.push("${name}Release: .env.${name}")
}
project.ext.envConfigFiles = variantsConfig
```

But I can't concatenate the configuration, I keep getting errors

Comment: "I keep getting errors" : **what** errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see the `project.ext.envConfigFiles` is a map `ConfigKey:'ConfigValue'`. However, you are generating a list in you second script. Your problems have great chances to come from that.

What you can do to correct that, and actually generate a Map:

```
def variantsJson = [
  'aaa',
  'bbb',
  ...
]

Map variantsConfig = [:]
variantsJson.each { name ->
    variantsConfig["${name}Debug"] =  ".env.${name}"        
    variantsConfig["${name}Release"] = ".env.${name}"
}

project.ext.envConfigFiles = variantsConfig
```

Comment: I believe this needs double quotes round the key and value strings in the loop

Comment: Yep @tim_yates it does, I forgot about the string management in Groovy.